# Network Multiplayer in Flash

Tags: flash, networking, multiplayer

Flash has come a long way in the last decade, and it's a well-kept secret getting a Flash game to connect to a multi-client server for chat and/or basic avatar movement in real time.

Why has the industry as a whole not made this a common-knowledge type of thing yet? We keep pushing to the web but I am finding it incredibly difficult gathering learning material on this subject.

Sure, I can find multi-client server socket tutorials in various languages (using select statements and/or threads to handle multiple socket connections), but in regards to Flash applications inside of a browser? NOPE!

Can everyone please share what they know? :] It's a subject I'd really love to get into but I'm afraid I just honestly don't know enough about how to do it.

Comment: I was looking into this very thing many years ago before Adobe was in the picture, and I telephoned Macromedia directly after not finding anything online.  They told me that only XML communications were supported, and that direct socket I/O simply wasn't possible and wasn't in the plans.  For an MMO, reading/writing specific bytes of data is important from a performance optimization standpoint, and XML carries ridiculous amounts of overhead for this sort of thing (it's wasteful to package/parse 50+ bytes to send/receive a few bytes of data repeatedly -- that CPU power should go to gameplay).

Answer (score 2):

The reason you cannot find any info about running a socket server from Flash within the browser is because it is not possible.  You can only connect to a socket server from a Flash movie running in the browser.

To run a socket server with Flash you need to create an AIR 2.x application that runs on the desktop.  This [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/communicating_with_sockets.html) on Adobe AIR Developer Center should get you started.

Comment: I meant exactly what you said - connecting to a socket server from flash, not running Flash AS a socket sever (I never even said that to begin with..)

Comment: You mentioned "multi-client server socket tutorials ... handl[ing] multiple socket connections".  I read that as wanting to run a socket server inside of Flash Player.  Anyway, the article I linked also explains how to connect to a socket server in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the reason you're not hearing much about Flash connecting to a multi-client server is possibly because you're researching only the Flash-side of things and not the server-side element.

It's less of a front-end / client-side issue, and more of a server-side management of state, connections (i.e. players), data (-base) updates, and what-not.

I've seen a nice abstraction used with [SmartFoxPro](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/products/pro.php). They offer the plug-and-play chat client, room client, in-game API that you can hook into as a flash / actionscript developer.

Honestly, you should take a look at multiplayer game development from the server-side perspective (java - [redwarf](http://www.reddwarfserver.org/), [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872639/simple-multiplayer-game-in-ruby-on-rails), python ([piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) as a framework), even php using a framework like codeigniter for a lightweight application).

Take a look at researching from that angle and hopefully that helps!